# How to get Logback in a custom layout when parameterized logging?

Tags: logback

I have created a custom layout.

Here is my code:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountLoginHelper.class);
...
log.info("Successful Login: {}", userName);
```

I can see in the debugger that userName is filled with "myid" before the call.

But the output in the message looks like this:

```
Successful Login: {}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
Successful Login: myid
```

This is the code in my customLayout:

```
@Override
public synchronized String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
    String message = event.getMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  Need to change

```
String message = event.getMessage()
```

to

```
String message = event.getFormattedMessage()
```